# I got Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 error in every flutter project

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

few days ago I tried to connect my flutter project with firebase and use it's sdk. I do exactly like the documentation, but since when I got these errors:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on STK L21 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

even when I create new flutter project , and run it I get these errors. I cant use `./gradlew` clean build either. I've tried every possible solution in internet but I couldn't fix it .
I'm going crazy , please help me .

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem few times and all the time when I use VPN or VPS .. the problem solved . I recommend you use VPN and run the project again